# Drawing in Tikz with conditional options on floats

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am currently trying to create an image of randomly distributed points in a unit-square.
I would like to draw these points in a given color if they are inside the inscribed circle, or in another, otherwise.

Here is what I have, without the condition set up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!10!white] (1,1) circle (1);
\draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{\xa=rand;}
    \tikzmath{\ya=rand;}
    \tikzmath{\eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);}
    \fill[red!60!white](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle(1.5pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have the fill/circle instruction have a color option that is dependent on the value of `\eval`, defined just above. For example:
If `\eval > 0` use `[red!60!white]`,
Otherwise, use `[blue!60!white]`

I tried using `\ifthenelse`, but am facing errors due (I think?) to the fact I am putting a condition on a float, and ifthenelse is limited to integers.

I also tried putting the fill/circle instruction inside a tikzmath environment, and having the condition set inside, but this did not work either, I believe because draw instructions cannot be called from inside that environment.

This would look like the following:

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{\xa=rand;}
    \tikzmath{\ya=rand;}
    \tikzmath{\eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);}
    \tikzmath{
        if \eval < 0 then {
            \fill[CERNblue!80!white](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle(1.5pt);
        } else {
            \fill[red!60!white](\xa+1, \ya+) circle(1.5pt);
        }
    }
}
```

Would anyone know how to go around these limitations?

Comment: Your last code example would work if you put braces around the TikZ statements, e.g. `{\fill … ;};`. See the [last example in the manual](https://tikz.dev/library-math).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code colors dots conditionally. Note that I had to brace `\x` and `\y` in `(\x)^2+(\y)^2` because if they are negative (say, -0.5 and -0,5) then the initial expression expands into `-0.5^2+-0.5^2` which is likely not what you expect. Also, the code uses `let` to assign strings to variable `\c`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!10!white] (1,1) circle (1);
\draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{
      \xa = rand;
      \ya = rand;
      \eval = (\xa)^2+(\ya)^2 - 1.0;
      if \eval<0 then {
        let \c = blue!80!white;
      } else {
        let \c = red!60!white;
      };
    }
    \fill[\c](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle(1.5pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You were really close with your last code example, you just need to enclose the TikZ statements in another pair of `{}` and add another `;`:

```
if \eval < 0 then {
   { \fill[blue!80!white](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt]; };
} else {
   { \fill[red!60!white] (\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt]; };
};
```

---

You can just do math with text, say

```
\col = \eval ? "blue!60!white" : "red!60!white";
% or 
\col = ifthenelse(\eval, "blue!60!white", "red!60!white")
```

Of course, you can also do this with `if`:

```
if \eval < 0 then {
  \col = "blue!60!white";% or let \col = blue!60!white;
} else {
  \col = "red!60!white"; % or let \col = red!60!white;
};
```

Assignments in the form of `\<var> = <stuff>` are evaluating `<stuff>` but you can also do `let \<var> = <stuff>` which does *not* evaluate `<stuff>`, that way you can drop the `"`.

Either way, now you can say

```
\fill[\col](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
```

---

Since `\eval` is a simple integer number, you could have also used TeX primitives, say

```
\fill[\ifnum\eval<0 blue\else red\fi !60!white](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
```

but that's not very nice.

---

Since you have only two outcomes depending on `\eval` you could define `my fill 0/.style=red!60!white`

and then use

```
\fill[blue!60!white, my fill \eval/.try](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
```

where `blue!60!white` acts as a default and the `/.try` will only try `my fill \eval` and won't complain when the style is not defined.

---

I always like to have an `if` key available that evaluates a statement and applies different styles depending on the value. That way, you can even say

```
\fill[/utils/if={ int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0)<0 }% conditional
                { blue!60!white }           % if true
                { red!60!white  }           % if false
  ] (\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
```

---

By the way, the `\foreach` macro allows to do math for every loop without the need for `\tikzmath`:

```
\foreach[
  evaluate={
    \xa=rand;
    \ya=rand;
    \eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);
  }] \i in {1,...,50}{
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{% always useful
  /utils/if/.code n args={3}{%
    \pgfmathparse{#1}\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\relax
    \expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo
      \else\expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\fi
    {\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!10!white] (1,1) circle[radius=1];
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{
      \xa=rand;
      \ya=rand;
      \eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);
      \col = \eval ? "blue!60!white" : "red!60!white";
    }
    \fill[\col](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!10!white] (1,1) circle[radius=1];
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{
      \xa=rand;
      \ya=rand;
      \eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);
      if \eval < 0 then {
        \col = "blue!60!white";% or let \col = blue!60!white;
      } else {
        \col = "red!60!white"; % or let \col = red!60!white;
      };
    }
    \fill[\col](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!10!white] (1,1) circle[radius=1];
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{
      \xa=rand;
      \ya=rand;
      \eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);
      if \eval < 0 then {
            {\fill[blue!80!white](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];};
        } else {
            {\fill[red!60!white](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];};
        };
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!10!white] (1,1) circle[radius=1];
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{
      \xa=rand;
      \ya=rand;
      \eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);
    }
    \fill[\ifnum\eval<0 blue\else red\fi !60!white](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[my fill 0/.style=red!60!white]
\fill[blue!10!white] (1,1) circle[radius=1];
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{
      \xa=rand;
      \ya=rand;
      \eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);
    }
    \fill[blue!60!white, my fill \eval/.try](\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[blue!10!white] (1,1) circle[radius=1];
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
    \tikzmath{
      \xa=rand;
      \ya=rand;
      \eval=int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0);
    }
    \fill[/utils/if={ int(\xa^2+\ya^2 - 1.0)<0 }% conditional
                    { blue!60!white }           % if true
                    { red!60!white  }           % if false
      ] (\xa+1, \ya+1) circle[radius=1.5pt];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```